# Weights initialization in Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis, weight-initialization

I was viewing code for custom neural network for sentiment analysis. It had 3 layers (1 hidden layer). I am more concerned with weight initialization for the layers

```
 self.weights_0_1 = np.zeros((self.input_nodes,self.hidden_nodes))
 self.weights_1_2 = np.random.normal(0.0, self.output_nodes**-0.5,(self.hidden_nodes,self.output_nodes))
```

What is the idea behind initializing zero's weight matrix. I have learned that initializing weights to zero might lead to linearity.

This might be a very vague question, I will be happy to provide any specifics you want.
https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning/blob/master/sentiment-network/Sentiment_Classification_Solutions.ipynb

Comment: Please provide the source, because as you already pointed out this is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Three layers with one hidden layer? This sounds wrong. You have 2 layers, input -> hides -> output, that's only 2 layers, with two sets of weights.

A single layer that gets initialized with only `0` will not converge, because the derivatives will be strictly identical (this rule also applies for any such last layer in a network, the layer gets basically useless). Here, there is a second layer **after** that saves the day, but it's still a bad practice in general.

Comment: I was considering Input, Output and hidden layer as three layer. Anyway I have edited the question, glad if you can help.